# Pin tool: wrap all routines with an entry/exit function via RTN_Replace

Tags: c, profiling, instrumentation, intel-pin, call-graph

Using Pin, I would like to call some instrumentation function before and after each application function call. I've read that `RTN_InsertCall` to add some entry/exit analysis functions with `IPOINT_BEFORE` and `IPOINT_AFTER` is unreliable as the exit may never be called.

My understanding is that the 'correct' way to do this is to replace the routine via `RTN_ReplaceSignature`, then in my replacement function add the entry and exit calls around a call to the original routine, where the original routine is called using `PIN_CallApplicationFunction`.

However, as far as I can tell `PIN_CallApplicationFunction` requires that I state in advance all of the arguments for the routine that I am wrapping, e.g., for `malloc` I would need to explicitly pass in some `size_t` argument, whereas for `free` I would pass in a pointer, and so on.

As I just want to wrap *all* function calls, I don't know the arguments! Is there some way to simply jump into the original function that I replaced, passing along the arguments for the original signature? Or perhaps some better way to do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can use a static analysis tool to autogenerate the replacement functions and then compile your tool with the result

Comment: That's seems a little inelegant but a good idea if there's no other way around the problem! Any idea of a lightweight static analysis tool that would suit? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with IPOINT_BEFORE, IPOINT_AFTER is that IPOINT_AFTER may miss some ret instructions. RTN_Replace functions will require a function pointer having the same signature as original (as you do not want to modify the default code).

A simple solution could be instrument all '**call**' and '**ret**' instructions. use **INS_Rtn** function to find out the routine name. This way you can instrument **all** functions without bothering for each function signature.